# Is Salesforce supports or provides Bulk API for SAP? Any experts suggestions please

Tags: integration, bulk-api

Bulk API documentation has given sample code in Java. We have a need where we need to load huge volume of data from SAP to Salesforce. Had tried using SOAP and RESTful services but ended with hitting the governor limits. Is that something that can be done exclusively in SAP and not through middleware written in Java ? Please suggest.

Sample Java given in the documentation. Like this, is Salesforce provides Bulk API support for SAP?

```
import com.sforce.async.*;
import com.sforce.soap.partner.PartnerConnection;
```

Do we have Bulk API support for SAP anyways? Experts suggestions please.